# Google analytics and Facebook pages/apps

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I have been doing a bit of research trying to figure out if i can get Google analytics to work with a Facebook app/page. So far I have looked at analytics offered by Facebook, which will be deprecated later this year and also using FBGAT to create a tracking image. from what i found, the tracking image won't work anymore and i was wondering what the community had to say about it or if it is possible to track traffic coming in to an app/page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook Insights aren't deprecated, some of the specific metrics are/were - these are itemised in the documentation.

You should have no problem using Google Analytics in your app; I believe many developers do this

Comment: thanks for the clarification, it seems i got a little confused in my research and didn't know about insights, i had looked up fb:google-analytics, but just knowing that it is possible is a relief.

Comment: Yeah, that `fb:google-analytics` is an old FBML tag, but apps work as iframes now so you can include Google Analytics directly, and also access the Facebook-provided insights on app usage either in the frontend at facebook.com/insights or via the API

Comment: thanks for the info, i look forward to having a play around! +1

Comment: @lgy: facebook apps not necessarily mean they are iframe apps. They can also run standalone. Just my two cents.

Comment: JPK was asking about an old FBML tag facebook which was supported for adding Google Analytics back when FBML was supported - now all apps.facebook.com apps are iframes and this tag is not supported, but you can include GA directly the same way you would for any other website